# How to get subscription data from client cache?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

i'm new to all the hot graphql/apollo stuff.

I have a subscription which gets a search result:

```
export const SEARCH_RESULTS_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
    subscription onSearchResultsRetrieved($sid: String!) {
        searchResultsRetrieved(sid: $sid) {
            status
            clusteredOffers {
                id
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Is it possible to query the "status" field from client cache if i need it inside another component? Or do i have to use an additional ?

In the apollo dev-tools i can see that there is a cache entry under "ROOT_SUBSCRIPTION" not "ROOT_QUERY". What does that mean?

....thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/1722

Answer (score 1):

I found out that [subscribeToMore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more) is my friend to solve this.
At first i wrote a normal query for the data i want to subscribe to have cached data, then the cache will be updated by the subscription.

<3 apollo